# There is some problem with Open cv's imshow function. And I do not understand it

Tags: python, opencv

**

```
error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-dglzv4yn/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:651: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

**

That is the error.
And this is the pseudo code.

**

```
import cv2
import numpy as n

path = 'something/else'
img = cv2.imread(path)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**

I am implementing this on a kaggle notebook to use for a image localization with bounding box project.
From what I've seen people only use open cv for drawing bounding boxes from labels to image.
Please also let me know if there are some other maybe easier ways to do it because I do not yet understand anything about open cv. Thanks.

Comment: if using kaggle notebook , i always use plt.imshow from matplotlib to display the image

Comment: I too do that. However I do not how to use plt.imshow from matplotlib to show bounding boxes for any given label.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error suggests?

Comment: to draw bbox, use cv2.rectange() on numpy array,& then you can pass that numpy array to plt.imshow() function ,this way u can also get bbox on your image@Clown

Comment: Thank you @PrajotKuvalekar. I've done that and it works. Please post that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use `matplotlib`'s `imshow()` method when using kaggle notebook
If you have numpy image and if you want to add bounding box use `cv2.reactangle()` method ,
then use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` to plot the same and it will work